# Will the python script to scrape google search results blocked by Google?

Tags: python, google-chrome, search

I am writing a Python script to scrape the first 10 pages of search results of >300 keywords per day. Will it be recognized and blocked by Google?

Or will I need to use its own API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview#pricing) which is not free?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why not try it?

Comment: yes it will be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely you will get blocked by Google at some point. That's where you should use rotating proxy. It changes the IP for every new connection, thus it is reduce the chance of getting blocked to minimum.

---

Solution like [SerpAPi](https://serpapi.com/) done all this work for you. Retrieving the data may be as simple as making an API call. It also provide formatted data in JSON. A sample Google search `https://www.google.com/search?q=Coffee` response looks like this

```js
{
   ...
   "local_map":{
      "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Coffee&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rldoc=1&rllag=30267328,-97742779,104&tbm=lcl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQtgN6BAgeEAc",
      "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/2c7265ad4a543339817d42073c4c5df8.png",
      "gps_coordinates":{
         "latitude":30.267328,
         "longitude":-97.742779,
         "altitude":104
      }
   },
   "local_results":{
      "more_locations_link":"https://www.google.com/search?tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:9&tbm=lcl&q=Coffee&rflfq=1&num=10&uule=w+CAIQICIaQXVzdGluLFRleGFzLFVuaXRlZCBTdGF0ZXM&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQjGp6BAgeEGE",
      "places":[
         {
            "position":1,
            "title":"Starbucks",
            "place_id":"10605736027611436825",
            "lsig":"AB86z5XTJ_Io_anVBu2fU6Zaqu3b",
            "place_id_search":"https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&location=Austin%2C+Texas%2C+United+States&lsig=AB86z5XTJ_Io_anVBu2fU6Zaqu3b&ludocid=10605736027611436825&q=Coffee&tbm=lcl",
            "reviews":506,
            "price":"$$",
            "type":"Coffee shop",
            "address":"600 Congress Ave",
            "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/1da898cc867dbcb3d01977dd6a88324830a17bef6769367010e21458fda67be97c9c3f66ca35fbd3.jpeg",
            "gps_coordinates":{
               "latitude":30.26826,
               "longitude":-97.74296
            }
         },
         {
            "position":2,
            "title":"Houndstooth Coffee",
            "place_id":"11265938073076301333",
            "lsig":"AB86z5Vdw6C2pJpM0xQ6JUx2KONU",
            "place_id_search":"https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&location=Austin%2C+Texas%2C+United+States&lsig=AB86z5Vdw6C2pJpM0xQ6JUx2KONU&ludocid=11265938073076301333&q=Coffee&tbm=lcl",
            "reviews":740,
            "price":"$$",
            "type":"Coffee shop",
            "address":"401 Congress Ave #100c · In Frost Bank Tower",
            "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/1da898cc867dbcb3d01977dd6a883248c09e12c31822db27da4d3f71793b876103709dcadd9705be.jpeg",
            "gps_coordinates":{
               "latitude":30.2664,
               "longitude":-97.74278
            }
         },
         {
            "position":3,
            "title":"Lucky Lab Coffee",
            "place_id":"10608433616590646585",
            "lsig":"AB86z5X1H_n2-O4x616ohROZpOhi",
            "place_id_search":"https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&location=Austin%2C+Texas%2C+United+States&lsig=AB86z5X1H_n2-O4x616ohROZpOhi&ludocid=10608433616590646585&q=Coffee&tbm=lcl",
            "reviews":2,
            "type":"Cafe",
            "address":"515 Congress Ave · In the Bank of America Financial Center",
            "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/1da898cc867dbcb3d01977dd6a88324886cadf9d168daae110c2dd1a08b2d23547f91a9442817f71.png",
            "gps_coordinates":{
               "latitude":30.267742,
               "longitude":-97.74261
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "knowledge_graph":{
      "title":"Coffee",
      "type":"Drink",
      "header_images":[
         {
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c8bfff7eefb2c6d74eee99d69c4481dd1679df8e9c6a784e9.jpeg",
            "source":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee"
         },
         {
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c8bfff7eefb2c6d747d1b7b1de6208d46ae515ba41bd21677.jpeg",
            "source":"https://www.nbcnews.com/better/lifestyle/how-tap-health-benefits-coffee-ncna1096031"
         },
         {
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c8bfff7eefb2c6d748906d5985fcefcd48ad5887b4e84fc15.jpeg",
            "source":"https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/food-and-drink/coffee-weight-loss-healthy-nutritional-value-fat-burn-diet-metabolism-a8296946.html"
         },
         {
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c8bfff7eefb2c6d745a2748e50daa1b02ad752b079122ff3f.jpeg",
            "source":"https://austin.eater.com/maps/best-coffee-austin-cafes-patio-latte-pour-over"
         }
      ],
      "description":"Coffee is a brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, the seeds of berries from certain Coffea species. From the coffee fruit, the seeds are separated to produce a stable, raw product: unroasted green coffee.",
      "source":{
         "name":"Wikipedia",
         "link":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee"
      },
      "patron_saint":"Saint Drogo of Sebourg redrockroasters.com",
      "patron_saint_links":[
         {
            "patron_saint_text":"redrockroasters.com",
            "patron_saint_link":"https://www.redrockroasters.com/shop-accessories/saint-drogo-pocket-retablo"
         }
      ],
      "chicory_coffee":[
         {
            "name":"Cafe Du Monde Coffee",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Cafe+Du+Monde+Coffee&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAA3Iuw3CMBAAUEUoEhQ0KANElDSH00RKG1pmsIJ9_ijnOwcD2YeSCRgPXvm2m8MOEpy71-LScQ8elApKL77rw6mZzQBGUhIerKy8TndbPpX6HxGaRxSGmWUltB51nhipQAmSc2Sv56yRoo83wnfdjJPD9vJsr8IW21GcQ_zW1Q_6j3k0gAAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg7EAU",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c0f6e783ada4b70fd6842017d38d47bed2998db83edddf2f6.jpeg"
         },
         {
            "name":"12 oz. Ground Pure Chi...",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=12+oz.+Ground+Pure+Chicory&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAA3IMQ6CMBQA0BBDooOLcXJqHB38FDdWB1dvQLD9lNL2_1oEosdx9AQeT9_4lovNCgIU5XRvw34NBqRsu37Sp6I_bJ2qQHEITJXmmeYm6eGTyf95j-phmcARzx61wTo2hH6AoeMYLZnaxRq9Nfbm8Z3vZCn4dRSXxCNpcR0TinNnFafnN89-R-f-lYYAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg7EAc",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c0f6e783ada4b70fd6ffaf528a1df5363c5721124b0c4d0d0.jpeg"
         },
         {
            "name":"Monterey Bay Spice Chicory...",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Monterey+Bay+Spice+Chicory+Root+Roasted+Granules+1+LB+Bags+Natural+Coffee+and+Tea+Substitute+Caffeine+Free+Beverage+Certified+Kosher&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAA2MPU7EMBBGFaGVoKBBHGBESWOCtM2WWQkKfgqWPpq1x44VZ8bYTqL0nISSE3A83HzF-57e5cXNlZrUw-PyZae7a-VU29p9Wvppv93fjvqgtEyT8MHIyismk3-btrIQSBcvrEaWNZBx1EdkClnlQWL07Pox9hS88-dAP7vv5k24UKINOtzgFL0mOA5eS9rgQ6TUwVzIwHNCngNlaOG1q7LL8I5lThjgKNYSAbKBT0I4zedcfJlLLWF9PBM8pSp0tFBCVzGl4q2v1RfJA6W_XfMPNZovy_EAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg7EAk",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c0f6e783ada4b70fd66c3eead310388e95fa3a7d9b692e6d5.jpeg"
         },
         {
            "name":"Herbaila Chicory Roasted...",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Herbaila+Chicory+Roasted+Root+Granules+Lb+Coffee+Free+Tea+Natural+Substitute+%26+Pound+New&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAA3IPWrDQBBAYYQR2EWa4AMMLlyk2SgpDG4NtotggpMinZjVjuS1Znfk_YnwdVLmBDle1LwP3nz2uFBOPb9831q3elCdqqpr1YfXjQtPy77ZqkacE781MvoRg4m_RTU9ZmqSFa96LyOT6age0BNHFS8yDNZ3dT_UxLazmumn_DpS0GgZYXexjYQ7nAVjIjMpCQ4BfWaK8KZhJ21LBPsw5ZMQTphyQIaPrGOyKSeCNbxL9gZONP6VxT_Ryrt-xAAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg7EAs",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c0f6e783ada4b70fd80f296058a363e88e80a2c1b567a76c1.jpeg"
         },
         {
            "name":"Community Coffee Coffee...",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Community+Coffee+Coffee+%26+Chicory+Ground+Coffee&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAADXMPw6CMBSA8RBDooOL8QCNg4PLE0dWBo_RYPsoDe17_QMSruPoCTyeDDp9yW_4tpvDDjxcb8_Y-dMeDFRVzD76KMPlOKgaFHvPVGueaW6Tzu-iWs05VKNlgoF4dqgNytASugy55xAsGTkEic4a-3D4KqFZNxPZcRENdx3iP2fR9FZxWsQ98UT655-y-AJrgg6MmwAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg7EA0",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c0f6e783ada4b70fdec4a6b7871ef989286cf3b6521287889.jpeg"
         }
      ],
      "chicory_coffee_link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Chicory+coffee&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtVQjC1RLKTrfST83Nz8_OsUvLL88oTi1KKVzEaAsVyclKTSzLz8_Sz8_LLc1JT0lPjCxLzUnOK9Ysz8gsKMvPS47ML4lNzMtMzk3JSF7HyOWdkJucXVSok56elpabuYGUEAEAR73d2AAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQMSgAegQIOxAB",
      "chicory_coffee_stick":"H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtVQjC1RLKTrfST83Nz8_OsUvLL88oTi1KKVzEaAsVyclKTSzLz8_Sz8_LLc1JT0lPjCxLzUnOK9Ysz8gsKMvPS47ML4lNzMtMzk3JSF7HyOWdkJucXVSok56elpabuYGUEAEAR73d2AAAA",
      "coffee_books":[
         {
            "name":"The World Atlas of Coffee: F...",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=The+World+Atlas+of+Coffee:+From+Beans+to+Brewing+-+Coffees+Explored,+Explained+and+Enjoyed&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAC3JQQqCQBSAYSSEWrQoOsCjZRSjQRDuMuwEQdBudN6YOvNezUjadVp2go5XRLuf7x8OpiNhRbS-37Sdj0Up4jjfmH5b1vVi1hSJKNhapkRxR510yr-CydeMwaKtmETO3PhneD5eEE7sjIJda6QH1rBnrRETODi2kKIkDy1D6rCrqITV_3vI-qthh2r5K1kRKpCkIKOaH6jeYfABYiUriKYAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg9EAU",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c731197c286d418eafe8e1d75f61c7e84a5f4ff7386100ca7.jpeg"
         },
         {
            "name":"Craft Coffee: A Manual",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Craft+Coffee:+A+Manual&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtV4tVP1zc0TKmwTDe2yC7TEslOttJPzs_Nzc-zSskvzytPLEopXsUoCBTLyUlNLsnMz9NPys_PLl7EKuZclJhWouCcn5aWmmql4Kjgm5hXmpizg5URAFoyNJBiAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg9EAc",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c731197c286d418eae2ca32b7fe5a3965f293af100e280f16.jpeg"
         },
         {
            "name":"The Blue Bottle Craft of...",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=The+Blue+Bottle+Craft+of+Coffee:+Growing,+Roasting,+and+Drinking,+with+Recipes&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAB2IMQrCMBRAESkouCge4OMoQrRO7WgFN4fiBdLkpw1N8jWJxvM4egKPZ-nyeO_Npqs5s2yfvx7KbhasZYe8scWxkO_tuhclE2QtuVJScol7Gb6T5fCMQRE1OdYQ9eGTXW8dwsk8B1CMBqHyXEUgBRUphVjCxVPSrt1BTTzE0biTcPba9WMlHTuoUeg7hl82-QNFNQFmmQAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg9EAk",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c731197c286d418ea2a4c4491e5b91967e98490fc47b5439b.jpeg"
         },
         {
            "name":"The Professional Barista's...",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=The+Professional+Barista%27s+Handbook&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtV4tFP1zc0SsrNzS0qttASyU620k_Oz83Nz7NKyS_PK08sSilexSgIFMvJSU0uyczP00_Kz88uXsSqHJKRqhBQlJ-WWlwMFE7MUXBKLMosLklUL1bwSMxLASnbwcoIAIZvHchuAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg9EAs",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c731197c286d418ea34890ccba17763b33af30dbf2d1cf08b.jpeg"
         },
         {
            "name":"Everything But Espress...",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Everything+But+Espresso:+Professional+Coffee+Brewing+Techniques&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtV4tVP1zc0TKkqLjdLKTfTEslOttJPzs_Nzc-zSskvzytPLEopXsUoCBTLyUlNLsnMz9NPys_PLl7Eau9allpUWZKRmZeu4FRaouBaXFCUWlycb6UQUJSfBmQB1SbmKDjnp6Wlpio4FaWWg1SGpCZn5GUWlqYW72BlBACYMYYFiwAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg9EA0",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c731197c286d418ea3a06871f9d0f679705e1fe6f7915c558.jpeg"
         }
      ],
      "coffee_books_link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Coffee+books&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtVQjC1RLKTrfST83Nz8_OsUvLL88oTi1KKVzEKAsVyclKTSzLz8_ST8vOzixex8jjnp6WlpiqAuTtYGQHBbXIpVAAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQMSgAegQIPRAB",
      "coffee_books_stick":"H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtVQjC1RLKTrfST83Nz8_OsUvLL88oTi1KKVzEKAsVyclKTSzLz8_ST8vOzixex8jjnp6WlpiqAuTtYGQHBbXIpVAAAAA",
      "people_also_search_for":[
         {
            "name":"Tea",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Tea&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtV4gAxzZNzKrQEgzNTUssTK4v9UitKgktSC4oXsTKHpCbuYGUEAEjPygozAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg8EAU",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c8922f70020484e82863a1fb14ad7834ba7ce81bed561e6d405f00b65c2c336fb.jpeg"
         },
         {
            "name":"Espresso",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Espresso&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtV4gAxk0vSsrUEgzNTUssTK4v9UitKgktSC4oXsXK4FhcUpRYX5-9gZQQADwmvdzgAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg8EAc",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c8922f70020484e82863a1fb14ad7834bca0c55e3d185f15847b7398b104adad3.jpeg"
         },
         {
            "name":"Drink",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Beverage&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtV4tZP1zc0MkoryDMr0hIMzkxJLU-sLPZLrSgJLkktKF7EyuGUWpZalJieuoOVEQCpF_cVOwAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg8EAk",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c8922f70020484e82863a1fb14ad7834bb8f7bd4c5777e7c99a90f6440d6de376.jpeg"
         },
         {
            "name":"Bakery",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Bakery&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtV4gIzy8vMSjK0BIMzU1LLEyuL_VIrSoJLUguKF7GyOSVmpxZV7mBlBAAYMLooOAAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg8EAs",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c8922f70020484e82863a1fb14ad7834b57c37e90b1da558036eee2476bbeeca1.jpeg"
         },
         {
            "name":"Iced coffee",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Iced+coffee&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtVAjNNs5PKDLUEgzNTUssTK4v9UitKgktSC4oXsXJ7JqemKCTnp6Wlpu5gZQQADVX9azwAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQxA16BAg8EA0",
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c8922f70020484e82863a1fb14ad7834bab658e29bb3ef9fcbaff7da83ed64051.jpeg"
         }
      ],
      "people_also_search_for_link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=Coffee&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtVQjC1BIMzU1LLEyuL_VIrSoJLUguKF7GyOeenpaWm7mBlBABkIv_mNwAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUxqjxgMXzAhUhmWoFHfPSA5QQMSgAegQIPBAB",
      "people_also_search_for_stick":"H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MCorTMtVQjC1BIMzU1LLEyuL_VIrSoJLUguKF7GyOeenpaWm7mBlBABkIv_mNwAAAA",
      "see_results_about":[
         {
            "name":"Coffee",
            "extensions":[
               "Plant"
            ],
            "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/3da5c3104e4a51e58340d10119d9ef0c4dbfdfcfff1cbe01c2e0271548875123a645e28ce8634e54d852f39ec78d2cfe.jpeg"
         }
      ],
      "list":{
         "total_fat":[
            "0 g",
            "0%"
         ],
         "saturated_fat":[
            "0 g",
            "0%"
         ],
         "trans_fat_regulation":[
            "0 g"
         ],
         "cholesterol":[
            "0 mg",
            "0%"
         ],
         "sodium":[
            "5 mg",
            "0%"
         ],
         "potassium":[
            "116 mg",
            "3%"
         ],
         "total_carbohydrate":[
            "0 g",
            "0%"
         ],
         "dietary_fiber":[
            "0 g",
            "0%"
         ],
         "sugar":[
            "0 g"
         ],
         "protein":[
            "0.3 g",
            "0%"
         ],
         "caffeine":[
            "95 mg"
         ],
         "vitamin_c":[
            "0%"
         ],
         "calcium":[
            "0%"
         ],
         "iron":[
            "0%"
         ],
         "vitamin_d":[
            "0%"
         ],
         "vitamin_b6":[
            "0%"
         ],
         "cobalamin":[
            "0%"
         ],
         "magnesium":[
            "1%"
         ]
      }
   },
   ...
}
```

Try it our from [Playground](https://serpapi.com/playground). You can also sign up to get free searches.

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.